# How to pass a variable from Django to Typescript?

Tags: django, typescript

In Django I have a template file that looks somewhat like this:

#### my_template.html:

```
<script>
let config = '{{ my_config_variable }}';
</script>
<script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>
```

#### script.ts:

```
// do something with the config variable:
console.log(config);
```

This would work in JavaScript, because JavaScript doesn't care. But if I try to compile this in TypeScript, I, of course, get error.

So, what the right way to pass some variables from Django to TypeScript (and maintain some type safety if possible)?

## Edit:

I have changed things to this, and it works but I am not sure if that's the way to got.

#### my_template.html:

```
<script>
let config = '{{ my_config_variable }}';
main(config);
</script>
<script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>
```

#### script.ts:

```
function main(config) {
    // do something with the config variable:
    console.log(config);
}
```

Comment: This question is really about how to define global variables in TypeScript, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**script.ts**:

```
console.log((window as any).config)
```

or

```
interface IWindow {
  config: any
}
declare let window: IWindow
console.log(window.config)
```

Your edited example with `main('{{ my_config_variable }}')` is fine but should be after the `script.js` script element.